# Why do we need `order by` in row_number() over(order by column name)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, row-number

Why we should use "order by" in over phrase in this t-sql term:

```
row_number() over(order by column name)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are asking why it is mandatory to place the `ORDER BY` clause in the [`OVER CLAUSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) (other than just because the `ANSI spec` requires it), which you may consider to be redundant as it is in addition to the overall `ORDER BY` clause which would be placed at the end of the query.

The usefulness of the `ORDER BY` in the [`OVER()` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) is because you may wish to apply a *different `ORDER BY` to the overall query*, than the ordering applied when determining the column generated by the partitioned `ROW_NUMBER()` function. Consider the following query, where we want to apply a ranking to the population of a city within (`PARTITION BY`) of the city, but ordered alphabetically by country name and city name:

Assuming `City` has `(CountryName, CityName, Population)`

```
select CountryName, CityName, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CountryName 
                          ORDER BY Population DESC) AS RankedPopulation
FROM City
ORDER BY CountryName, CityName;
```

Which could present a result like so:

```
CountryName     CityName       RankedPopulation
--------------- -------------- -----------------
England         Liverpool      2
England         London         1
France          Lyons          2
France          Paris          1
USA             Los Angeles    2
USA             Miami          3
USA             New York       1
```

If you have multiple columns projected from the analytic functions, each of these can have independent orderings in the respective `OVER` clauses.

Note in my example above, [`RANK` would be a more appropriate choice than `ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) - I just wanted to retain the context of your question.

[SqlFiddle of the example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f978a/1)

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

> Defines the logical order of the rows within each partition of the
>   result set. That is, it specifies the logical order in which the
>   window functioncalculation is performed.

Answer (score 1):

Row_Number actually uses this scenario:
suppose that we have this records(5,3,4,1,6)
in row number we say that how many elements are exist, that their value is lower than the current one? to answer this question we need to have an ordered list. if not we need to iterate among whole list to find out the real count.